# How to combine materialboxed with materialize carousell?

Tags: html, css, frameworks, carousel, materialize

I have previously tried materialboxed for card images and it worked.

But when I use materialboxed for carousel images the result is different, not as good as the card image.

The fixed navigation bar and any of the elements below also look different from the card image, for which all the surrounding elements are invisible.

I have tried to edit css from materialize but still can't.

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" class="materialboxed"></a>
  </div>
```

[the result image materialboxed in carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRB5i.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> The navigation bar and any of the elements below also look different from the card image, for which all the surrounding elements are invisible.

Does this mean that when you are using the class `materialboxed` with the `img` tags in the `carousel` that the rest of the page does not become invisible/blacked-out when you click on the image?

Perhaps you have more code in your document that you did not share?

I was able to achieve the `materialboxed` effect in your carousel with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <!-- IMPORT MATERIALIZE CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="carousel">
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" class="materialboxed"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" class="materialboxed"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" class="materialboxed"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" class="materialboxed"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" class="materialboxed"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- IMPORT MATERIALIZE JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- INIT CAROUSEL -->
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
          var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
      });
    </script>

    <!-- INIT MATERIALBOXED -->
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
          var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems);
      });
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

See [screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKA3F.jpg) for result.

EDIT 2020-10-23:

Several assumptions for the following:

`materialize.js` is now local to the html file instead of imported from CDN. Also, the `<nav>` tag is now wrapped in a div with `class="navbar-fixed"` and `id="fixed-nav"`:

```
<div id="fixed-nav" class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        {...}
    </nav>
</div>
```

In comments, OP clarified that he doesn't like the behavior when using `materialboxed` + `carousel` + `navbar-fixed`.

One solution would be to remove the class `navbar-fixed` from `<nav>`'s wrapper div when opening a carousel image and adding it back when closing.

At line 3590 and 3722 of `materialize.js` are the functions to open and close, respectively, an image with class `materialboxed`. Inside these functions, you can add the following to remove/add `navbar-fixed` from your  wrapper with id `fixed-nav`:

Inside the `open()` function:

```
// remove navbar-fixed
let fixedNav = document.getElementById('fixed-nav')
fixedNav.classList.remove('navbar-fixed')
```

Inside the `close()` function:

```
// add navbar-fixed
let fixedNav = document.getElementById('fixed-nav')
fixedNav.classList.add('navbar-fixed')
```

Comment: sorry before I forgot to say that it happened in fixed navbar not in normal navbar.

Comment: just try giving the fixed navbar class and see what happens if you click on carousel image, the result is like i said before

Comment: I was able to replicate the behavior you describe. I edited my answer with a solution that will work to open the image without the fixed nav and to re-active fixed nav when closing the image.

I wouldn't recommend modifying materialize.js heavily, but it was relatively easy to do it this way since many event listeners are encapsulated in the `open()` and `close()` functions I described in my edit. Apologies for the delay.